# How to update a listView after execution of image trigger inside ViewModel in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a class `Product`

```
 public class Product:ObservableObject,  IKeyObject
    {
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
        public string Id { get; set; }     //this is cause i am using sqlite
        //other properties
        public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }        
    }
```

I also have a **ViewModel** `ProductVm` that inherits from `BaseViewModel` and this class `BaseViewModel` inherits from `ObservableObject` like

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    protected INavigation Navigation;

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => _isBusy;
        set { _isBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    protected BaseViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
    }
    protected BaseViewModel()
    {
    }        
}


public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Now, **ViewModel** `Product` has an `ObservableCollection<Product>` 
and a command 
inside a page `PageProduct`, there is a binding of the view model so list can be updated depending on changes on a listView `ProductResults`

```
public class ProductVm : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Product> _productResults = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductResults
    {
        get => _productResults ;
        set {  _productResults = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public ICommand FavoriteProductCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private void FavoriteProduct(Product product)
    {
        //here I tried traversing the  ObservableCollection<Product> 
        // and then update the value with the product.IsFavorite value
        //the item gets updated but the GUI does not    
        var item = _productResults.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == product.Id);
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.IsFavorite = product.IsFavorite;
        }
    }
    public ProductVm()
    {
        FavoriteProductCommand= new Command<Product>(FavoriteProduct);
    }
```

Now inside **PageProduct** (named `MyProductPage` so I could use command and pass a product object in ViewModel) I have **listView** `ProductFeed`, and inside it has a grid that contains a button and an image, this image loads `pincturea.png` if `product.IsFavorite` is **false**, in other case it loads `pinctureb.png` I do this by using triggers like:

```
           <ListView x:Name="ProductFeed"
                  HasUnevenRows="true"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ProductResults}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                     <Grid WidthRequest="30"
                                      HeightRequest="30">                                        
                                    <Image BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                           IsOpaque="True"
                                           x:Name="ImgFavorite"
                                           >
                                        <Image.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                                         Binding="{Binding IsFavorite}" 
                                                         Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="Source"
                                                        Value="pincturea.png" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                                         Binding="{Binding IsFavorite} "
                                                         Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Source"
                                                        Value="pictureb.png" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Image.Triggers>

                                    </Image>
                                    <Button
                                        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.FavoriteProductCommand, Source={x:Reference MyProductPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        BorderColor="Transparent"
                                        Opacity="0.1">
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

## Problem

I want that after user clicks on displayed button (that shows either `pincturea.png` o `pinctureb.png`) it updates collection value and also the GUI 
so it updates the shown image

## Searched solutions

After searching I saw that everybody says that it has to do with a 
`INotifyPropertyChanged` issue, but as far as I know I already did that part 
doing this

```
 public class ProductVm : BaseViewModel
```

and also declaring

```
private ObservableCollection<Product> _productResults = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductResults
        {
            get => _productResults ;
            set {  _productResults = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

Other solutions involve:

```
listview.isRefreshing = true;
//update observableCollection
listview.isRefreshing = false;
```

but as I am working on ViewModel I do not have access to listview there..

What am I missing, so in my method

```
private void FavoriteProduct(Product product)
```

I can update GUI too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling property changed in your model

Try this

```
public class Product:ObservableObject,  IKeyObject
    {
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
        public string Id { get; set; }     //this is cause i am using sqlite
        //other properties
        private bool _isFavorite;
        public bool IsFavorite
        {
          get => _ isFavorite;
          set { _ isFavorite = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        } 

    }
```